# $.get won't execute without following function

Tags: jquery, get

It's been a long time since I've done any jQuery/js stuff, and silly $.get() is giving me problems.  I'm in a purely testing stage, and just want to use $.get to return a json-encoded string.

This is what I would like to use:

```
<script>
  function send_address(){
    $.get("tester3.php", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

However, the only way I can get a response is by using this (which executes out of order, but I understand that is a result of an asynchronous call, and isn't the issue):

```
<script>
  function send_address(){
    $.get("tester3.php", function(data){
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      });
    alert('here');
  }
</script>
```

I just want to send a get request to "tester3.php" and see the returned string without having to put in the alert.

Thanks, and happy holidays!

**UPDATED:**
Here's the html that calls the function:

```
<form id="maps_check" class="niceform">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="send_address()"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting. I can't really explain this. Is send_address being executed in the first sample?

Comment: Not that I can tell. I need the alert function to follow in order to see any response from the $.get.

Comment: You can check in your JavaScript console. You definitely need to stop normal submission as Krister says. Check for JS errors; there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: When I console.log(data), it says that there is an Uncaught ReferenceError, as data is not defined.  This is probably because of the asynchronous call executing out of order. When you say "stop normal submission," do you mean to start using callbacks, as Chibuzo suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling the `send_address` on a click or submit event I think you should try to return `false`.

```
function send_address(){
   $.get("tester3.php", function(data){
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
   return false;
}
```

You could also cancel the default action by using `preventDefault()` like this:

```
function send_address(e) {
   // cancel the action when clicking on a link
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I also put it in the document.ready function.

Comment: @user1114864 - I though you already had everything wrapped inside `$(document).raady`, good you solved it though=)

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function

```
<script>
    function send_address(callback){
        $.get("tester3.php", function(data){
            callback(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Use your response data this way

```
send_address(function(data) {
    // data contains your ajax result
    $("#where-you-want-it").html(data); // Depending on what and how you want to use it.
});
```

The callback will only execute after the asynchronous call completes.